# how correct distance between labels

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

could you tell me how can I set less distance between two labels in XAML - Xamarin.Forms. I have all margins=0 before this labels. The distance between to Labels was to long for me. I tried a few case and I fond resolution to set margin less than 0 (<0) but I think it's not the best.
My part of code:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding ObjecA.X}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="None" Margin="0,0,0,-5"/>
 <Label Text="{Binding ObjectB.X}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"  TextColor="Navy" Margin="0,-5,0,-2"/>
```

Could you tell me is better resolution?
Thanks

Comment: maybe you want to modify their padding as well.
Why are they labels? is there a specific reason for not using TextBlock?

Comment: Are your Labels inside a StackLayout? If so try setting the StackLayout **Spacing** Property to 0. Also, if you could show an image of the issue you are having.

Comment: Yes, I have Labels inside StackLayout

Comment: Do you think the textblock is better? I can us it

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if there is any chance your `Label` are in a `StackLayout`?

If so you can set up the `Spacing` property on the `StackLayout` itself. **By default it's 6.**

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
     <Label Text="{Binding ObjecA.X}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="None" Margin="0"/>
     <Label Text="{Binding ObjectB.X}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"  TextColor="Navy" Margin="0"/>
     ...
</StackLayout>
```

Then no need to play with the negative `Margin` anymore.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. But I had to set Spacing="-5". I don't understand why 0 isn't correct?

Comment: I cannot help more without your sample code, you should edit your post